# array of ifstream objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, iostream, ifstream, ofstream

I am trying to create an array of `ifstream` objects, the code compiles and I am able to create the array of `ifstream` objects of size `sizeargs-1` however once I try  to open a file in one of the `ifstream` objects the program crashes, it's very frustrating.

the reason I am trying it this was is that I have to dynamically create `ifstream` objects based on the number of `.ppm` files in memory and this seemed like the perfect solution, just being able to `ifstream_array[1].open(args[0]);` since I need to read text from multiple `.ppm` files simultaneously.

If doing this is impossible; is there an alternative way of doing it?

```
int main(int argc, char ** args)
{
        //counts number of .ppm files in array       
        int sizeargs = (sizeof(args)/sizeof(*args)); 

        ifstream inputfiles[sizeargs-1];

        int incounter = 0;

        //this is where the program crashes
        inputfiles[incounter].open(args[0]); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int sizeargs = (sizeof(args)/sizeof(*args)); //counts number of .ppm files in array
```

No, it doesn't. This evaluates to `sizeof(char**) / sizeof(char*)`, which is always 1. `sizeargs-1` is thus `0` and you have no items in your array. You cannot find the size of an array via a pointer to it. You need to use `argc`, which is the number of elements in `args`.

---

Based on the comments, you should also avoid variable length arrays, as they are availabe only with compiler extensions and are not part of the C++ standard. I would recommend using a vector instead:

```
    std::vector<std::ifstream> inputfiles(sizeargs-1);
```

Comment: In addition ifstream inputfiles[sizeargs-1]; isn't valid. The size of an array must be a constant. This is not standard C++ and will only work if the compiler allows an extension.

Comment: You're in C++. Why not use ``std::vector`` where the allocations and sizing are easier?

Comment: It's not really an array, but rather pointer to array of pointers.

Comment: Usually 1, not always.  There are (or have been) machines on which a `char*` is larger than a `char**` (in which case, it will be 0).

Comment: thanks, a classmate gave me that code (sizeof(args)/sizeof(*args));, I assumed it was correct, one problem I know to fix anyway

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
    int sizeargs = (sizeof(args)/sizeof(*args)); //counts number of .ppm files in array
```

will always yield `sizeargs` = 1 on <sup>*</sup>a modern compiler, since the size of a basic data pointer divided by the size of a basic data pointer, is 1.

---

In C++11 and earlier this statement:

```
    ifstream inputfiles[sizeargs-1];
```

is invalid, since the size of a (not dynamically allocated) raw array must be a compile time constant.

However, g++ offers C99 *variable length arrays* (VLAs) as a language extension.

---

Instead, use a `std::vector`.

<sup><sup>*</sup> As James Kanze points out in a comment to another answer, there have been machines where `sizeof(char*)` was larger than `sizeof(char**)`. Since `char` is the basic addressable unit, a `char*` pointer is the largest ordinary pointer. I didn't think that distinction would be relevant here, but reading James' comment (and we have discussed this in the past), I realized that my attitude to the "worth" of an SO answer, is wrong, and adjusted accordingly.</sup>